# rotation of hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

How can we rotate the rectangular hyperbola

xy=c   ( c is any constant)

Into a form of standard hyperbola that is

(x/a)$^2$ - (y/b)$^2$ = 1

By rotating the hyperbola .

Comment: Your title says you want to rotate an ellipse, while your question speaks of rotating a hyperbola. Then you ask about rotating the coordinate axes. These are all different things, and you should decide which one you're actually asking about.

Comment: What exactly would constitute an answer to your question? The $xy = c$ kind of hyperbola has been rotated $45^\circ$ compared to the "standard" kind of hyperbola; is that all that you're looking for?

Comment: @pjs36 yes , I am looking for that only

Comment: I see, and misspoke: What I said is true only for $(x/a)^2 - (y/a)^2 = 1$; i.e., when $a = b$. In general, when $a \neq b$, the hyperbolas aren't rotations of one another.

Comment: @pjs36 i have not given any relation between a and b . So you can take any value you want . Or could you explain me with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take $c^2$ instead $c$ for convenience like:

plugging in transformation relations for rotation  by $45^0$

$$ x =  (x_1 - y_1)/\sqrt2 \, ;  y = (x_1 + y_1)/\sqrt2 $$

into the equation of the rectangular hyperbola $ x\, y = c^2 $ and

you get it into standard  hyperbola form with new coordinate labels:

$$ (x_1/\sqrt2 c)^2  - (y_1/\sqrt2 c)^2  = 1. $$

[Axes Rotation](https://stemsoup.wordpress.com/tag/rotation-of-axes/)

Comment: How do we get the transformation relation

Comment: Direct trig of line lengths before and after rotation as above

Answer (score 1):

$xy = c$

let $x = u-v\\ y = u+v$

$xy = u^2 - v^2 = c$

Now the transformation that I have just done has a little bit of spacial compression to it.

If you do a traformation along the lines of $x = au-bv, y = bu+av$ then there will be compression on the order of  $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$  So, it is not a bad idea to choose $a,b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$

or $x = \cos \phi u - \sin\phi v\\ y = \sin\phi u + \cos\phi v$

and by trig identity that $cos^2 \phi + sin^2 \phi = 1$

$x = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} u-\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}v\\ y = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}u+\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}v\\
xy = \frac {u^2}2 + \frac {v^2}2 = c\\
 \frac {u^2}{2c} + \frac {v^2}{2c} = 1 $

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}=\mathcal{Rot}_{\text{cw}}(45)\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos45&-\sin45\\\sin45&\cos45\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\
\implies X=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\quad;\quad Y=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
$$
xy=c\implies \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}.\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{2}}=c\\\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}c}-\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{2}c}=1
$$
$$
\color{blue}{xy=c \iff \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}c}-\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{2}c}=1}
$$